Error when trying to Test reports from APEX APPLICATION ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
I have an Oracle Apex application where I want to create a report query and test it in shared components/Report Queries , My query is simple as a below:
Select * from LtrTBL;
when I want to test a query,  I get the error ORA-29273: HTTP request failed.
I run successfully below code to add Apex application owner account (APEX_200200) to ACL
`
DECLARE
ACL_PATH VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;
IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_200200',
'connect') IS NULL THEN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
'APEX_200200', TRUE, 'connect');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
-- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
'APEX_200200', TRUE, 'connect');
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/`

But I still get the above error.
the Listener File content is:
`# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Oracle193\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
Generated by Oracle configuration tools.`
`SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
(SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
(ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle193)
(PROGRAM = extproc)
(ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle193\bin\oraclr19.dll")
)
)
LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
)`
TNSNames file content is :
`# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Oracle193\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
Generated by Oracle configuration tools.`
`
LISTENER_ORCL =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-D62QNTA)(PORT = 1521))
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SID = CLRExtProc)
(PRESENTATION = RO)
)
)
ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-D62QNTA)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
)
)
`
SQL NET File content is :
`# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Oracle193\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora
Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to
install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native
authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.`
`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
also run TNSPING  command Result is:
C:\Users\Administrator>TNSPING LISTENER_ORCL
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 11-MAY-2024 01:32:45
Copyright (c) 1997, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Used parameter files:
C:\Oracle193\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-D62QNTA)(PORT = 1521))
OK (10 msec)`
What can be the issue?
